# Is it possible to write debug.log from unity3d to my visual studio output window for wp8 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

How can i debug my unity3d project for windows phone 8. I can't read a log from unity3d. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps

https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/wp8-debugging.html

- if debugging doesn't help to resolve your issue it might be useful to examine UnityPlayer.log file. It's located on the phone and can be retrieved by utility called Windows Phone Power Tools. Don't forget to include this file with your bugs reports.

Answer (score 0):

if not the good old GUI.Label with a string that saves the debug will do the trick